# Modify variables outside function using mclapply

Tags: r, function, multicore, lapply, mclapply

It is easy to modify variables outside a function using `assign()` or `<<-`, even if the function is called with `lapply()`. But these tricks seem not working while calling function with `mclapply()`, the parallel version of `lapply()` in package `multicore`:

```
require(multicore)
f <- function(i) {
    x[i] <- x[i] + 1
    y[i] <<- y[i] + 1
}
x <- y <- 1:10
invisible(lapply(1:5, f))
x #  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10, not changed
y #  2  3  4  5  6  6  7  8  9 10, variables 1 to 5 changed

# Now running with mclapply
x <- y <- 1:10
invisible(mclapply(1:5, f))
x # 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10, not changed
y # 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10, not changed again!
```

How to do the same task - modifying variables outside the function - while calling function by `mclapply()`?

**I know this should be used with care**, because the parallel running functions may try to modify the same variable that can cause severe synchronization errors, however it is helpful in some cases.

Comment: It's just awful programming. You should make `f` return the new values, then assign them outside the `mclapply` call. Can you think of a particular situation where this would indeed be helpful, it might help with the discussion.

Comment: @flodel thanks, but my purpose is to modify a few values in very large datasets. It does not make sense that f copies the whole dataset just because of a few modifications.

Comment: @Ali -- if you are using `<<-` or `<-` you might find copies are being made regardless.